# issue with uploading large size image in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm facing problem when I resize the image. When I choose a image from gallery then it compress so small but when I get this image in another view controller then it show blurred. If increase the size of image resize than some image are uploaded but are not.

### code

```
@IBAction func imagegallery(_ sender: Any) {
    checkPermission()
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)   
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let select = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

    ## resize the image ##

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            let imaged = self.resizeImage(image: select, withSize: CGSize(width: 300 , height: 100))
            let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imaged, 0.75)!
            self.strBase64 = (imageData.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength64Characters))
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }    
    } 
}
```

### resize function

```
func resizeImage(image: UIImage, withSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    var actualHeight: CGFloat = image.size.height
    var actualWidth: CGFloat = image.size.width
    let maxHeight: CGFloat = withSize.width
    let maxWidth: CGFloat = withSize.height
    var imgRatio: CGFloat = actualWidth/actualHeight
    let maxRatio: CGFloat = maxWidth/maxHeight
    let compressionQuality = 0.5 //50 percent compression

    if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
        if(imgRatio < maxRatio) {
            //adjust width according to maxHeight
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight
            actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth
            actualHeight = maxHeight
        } else if(imgRatio > maxRatio) {
            //adjust height according to maxWidth
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth
            actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight
            actualWidth = maxWidth
        } else {
            actualHeight = maxHeight
            actualWidth = maxWidth
        }
    }

    let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: actualWidth, height: actualHeight)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    image.draw(in: rect)
    let image: UIImage  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, CGFloat(compressionQuality))
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    let resizedImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
    return resizedImage!
}
```

Comment: Use this -. https://newfivefour.com/swift-form-data-multipart-upload-URLRequest.html

Comment: i can not use multipart uploads with URLRequest .my php developer are not providing me this api

Comment: are you trying to fetch the image from the server?
correct me if i'm wrong, are these the steps you take?

VC1 -> Pick Image -> Upload Image -> Go to VC2 -> fetch from server -> display image in VC2

Comment: ^ if those are the steps you take, i suggest that when you go to VC2, just pass the image you get from VC1 (or cache it if it will be used to other views) since the upload might not have been finished if the image is large (since you don't do multipart upload.

Comment: how can i solve it ?? i already attach dispatch for convert base string 64